# Copy (Named) Table multiple times within the same sheet and change the tables names

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I'm building a project management spreadsheet where multiple teams are going to have a copy. I want to create a simple address book. I have the names of the teams in a table and using VBA, I create the [Master Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3lb2.png).

In the range `B4:D5` there is a simple table with three column names:

- Name
- Telephone
- Email

I have named this table (in Name Manager) as `ContactTeam1`

I want to copy and paste this exact 3x2 table to be below each corresponding team such as the image [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG104.png) and change each Named Table as `ContactTeam2`, `ContactTeam3` and so on.

The reason I want to use VBA is because, we have many different projects, so I want to automate the process as much as I can, for future projects as well.

I will fill in the tables with all the necessary information (Names,Phones,Emails) - by hand. The reason I want to use tables is that it has the benefit to auto-expand to include any new lines below the last.

As a bonus functionality, when somebody clicks the cell on top that contains the name of the Team. (`Team Blue`, `Team Red` etc.) all the emails of the corresponding range will be copied to clipboard, to be used in an email client. (This can be done easier with tables - one more reason I want to use them).

Comment: do you want it to be associated with a button or should it detect how many teams there are and copy the corresponding number of times ?

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried and where that fails. We are willing to help and improve, but we are not a code writing service.

Comment: luisarcher, I already have a sub procedure, which creates the Rows 2 and 3 of the sheet. This sub is assigned to a button, and when pressed it creates these rows.
Luuklag, actually I don't have any existing code regarding the thing I asked, simply because I never worked with Named Ranges "duplicating" before and renaming them, so I didn't know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
Sub Bouton()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim RangeName As String
    Dim CellAdd1, CellAdd2 As String

    For cnt = 2 To ActiveSheet.Range("NumberTimes")

        Set rng = Range("ContactTeam" & (cnt - 1))

        RangeName = "ContactTeam" & cnt
        CellAdd1 = Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + 3).Address
        CellAdd2 = Cells(rng.Row + 1, rng.Column + 5).Address 
        '+ 1 in the row so the named range goes from B4 to D5 

        Set cell = ActiveSheet.Range(CellAdd1, CellAdd2)
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=cell

        Range("ContactTeam1").Copy Range("ContactTeam" & cnt)

    Next cnt

End Sub
```

I'm not the best in VBA, but what this does is that it creates a new range each 3 cells and names it from `ContactTeam2` to whatever your limit is. I created a named range called `NumberTimes`. Basically, you tell it how many new ranges you want to be created.

Comment: Hello luisarcher, thank you for your reply. I really appreciate it. Your solution indeed creates named ranges as I asked in my question for every cell, but it does not copies the table as-is from `B4:D5`. Anyway, your solution actually gave me an idea on how exactly to approach this. I will come soon! Again, thank you very much.

Comment: I changed the code so you get your two rows in the named range. However, I suggest you to not put the columns title in the named range.

Answer (score 0):

easiest of all, i guess we can use dictionary here. would be faster but here he what i tested/tried , EXACTLY on your data and works.

Sub d()

Sheet1.Select

Range("b3").Select

Do

```
Range("b3:d4").Name = "mainteam"

 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select

Range("mainteam").Copy ActiveCell

 Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select

Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Name = "team" & i
```

i = i + 1

Loop While i <> 5

End Sub

Comment: i = any time you want to continue

Comment: you can delete- Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select